# How to find this integral? Any way to solve it quickly?

Tags: integration

Evaluate the following integral:
$$\int\frac{x^5}{(x-1)^2(x^2+1)}dx $$

Was trying to solve it with long division etc for an hour but didn't get to a solution. What is a simple way to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Use partial fraction decomposition:
$$
\int\frac{x^{5}}{\left(x-1\right)^{2}\left(x^{2}+1\right)}dx=\int\left(-\frac{1}{2\left(x^{2}+1\right)}+x+\frac{2}{x-1}+\frac{1}{2\left(x-1\right)^{2}}+2\right)dx
$$
See also [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5%2F((x-1)%5E2*(x%5E2%2B1))).

Comment: I believe you've forgotten the measure

Comment: Thanks, I have added it above.